# How do I disable Devises message - "You are already signed in." - when redirecting back the users index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a button on my web page that redirects my from the user index with params back to the user index.  My problem is that when I navigate back to the users_path through a button I get a message form devise saying "You are already signed in."  This happens even though I was not trying to sign in and was only navigating back to the same page but removing the params.

The button in question looks like,

```
<%= button_to "All Users", users_path, class: "button expand" %>
```

I searched all my files for instances of "You are already signed in." and the only refrence is in the devise.en.yml where it says    `already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I was using a button_to rather than a link_to.
A button_to attaches a POST request as opposed to a link_to which attaches a GET request.  With the attached post request rails was looking to a different action in the controller than the one intended.

If creating a refresh method on an index or show page always use a link_to helper or a helper that attaches a GET request.

Answer (score 18):

You can also edit the message in config/locales/devise.en.yml:

```
failure:
  already_authenticated: ''
```

Then wherever your flash messages are displayed in your view:

```
- if flash[:alert].present?
  ...
```

Comment: This seems the most public-api approach; useful if you link from another site to the sign-in page when they might already be logged in.

Comment: Good to know but that would remove the message everywhere, which I'm assuming most people wouldn't want to do.

Comment: Not sure which versions of `devise` this applies to, but the full key I was able to get to work for this was `en.devise.failure.already_authenticated`.

Answer (score 3):

The `DeviseController` is generating this message from method `require_no_authentication`. This method is used as a `before_filter` on pages like the one for signing in or other similar actions that are useless for signed in users. It redirect to the `after_sign_in_path` for the resource and sets that `flash` message. You'll have to either overwrite the `require_no_authentication` method or generate a new controller that does not use the `before_filter`.